# th:field ignores the placeholder value and sets 0

Tags: thymeleaf

th:field ignores the placeholder value and sets the default value to 0.

Model:

```java
@Entity
public class Employer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int id;
...
}
```

View:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="A1234" th:field="*{emloyer.id}">
```

What is being generated:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="A1234" value="0" id="emloyer.id" name="emloyer.id">
```

I want to understand why is value=0 being generated. If I change type of int to String it is ok. I even tried value="" and th:value="", but it is still being generated as value="0". I know that I can write id="emloyer.id" name="emloyer.id" instead of th:field="*{emloyer.id}". But I want to understand why it is behaves like that.
I want to show placeholder value instead of default. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default an `int` has the value `0`. It can't have no value. You could use an `Integer` set to `null`, then Thymeleaf will use `value=""`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. Am I have to write as follows:
@Id
    private Integer id

Comment: @paro Yes, that is correct. If you want me to more specific, you'll need to be more specific, too. Do you know the difference between `int`and `Integer` in Java?